# How can I edit the style of an object on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

Simply trying to learn javascript, right now trying to get my content (which is simply just a redbox at this time) to expand once hovered over.
Don't see what I'm doing wrong. Help is greatly appreciated.

My html:

```
<div class="content" onmouseover="expand()"></div>
```

My css:

```
 .content
    {
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
      background-color:red;
      margin:auto;
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
      right:0;
      left:0;
      bottom:0;
    }
```

My javascript:

```
function expand()
{
  var content = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
  content.style.width = "200px";
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("content")` doesn’t return a single element but an `HTMLCollection`. You have to pick one particular element out of it.

Comment: Thank you so much @HovercraftFullOfEels new to the language thank you so much for the advice

Comment: @LynnEugeniaEspinoza It’s not about your grammar. It’s about categorization on this page. Again, if you want your solution, _you should make sure that others can actually find your question_.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! When you post a problem like this, please include the actual behaviour of your code - when you run it, what happends? Any errors in the console?

Comment: @Xufox how would I do that? Would just using getElementById be a better solution?

Comment: Add an `[0]` after `getElementsByClassName("content")`. You could also benefit from using debugging tools like JSHint or the browser console.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It was intended towards Andy, for I didn't know why he was correcting me, my comment was then edited since you better explained why categorization is so very important. I don't appreciate the rudeness since I am still figuring all this out.

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice will do for the troubleshooting. thank you.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza how could this be applied to my code? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
var content = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
```

Because [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an HTMLCollection. (For more info on how this works, check the info in the link).

A quick fix will be to retrieve the first element from the result:

```
var content = document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0];
```

But this will only work for the first DOM element with this class, for other elements they will simply be ignored.

Another solution may be passing the current element to the function by using `this`, then updating the style of the element accordingly.

```
<div class="content" onmouseover="expand(this)"></div>

function expand(elem) {
    elem.style.width = "200px";
}
```

And a third (and IMO better) option is to do it using CSS [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%3Ahover).

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution Luiggi!

Comment: For future reference- if I wanted an array of elements to perform the same function, how would I go about that? Sorry if it's asking too much

Comment: @LynnEugeniaEspinoza use a `for` loop and change every element in the array, if possible.

Comment: @LynnEugeniaEspinoza Common way to turn array-like collections into real array is to use `Array.prototype.slice`: `[].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("content"))` will give you reall array of elements.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using javascript to expand you can use CSS itself:

```
.content:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

change the 1.5 to however much you want to scale it.

Comment: Thank you, but I want to learn how to do so in Javascript to better learn the language. Also to make another object expand when the parent element or another element is hovered upon.